# How to create multiple parent actors in Thespian

Tags: python, actor-model

Working on Actor Model-based system and using the [Thespian library](https://thespianpy.com/doc/using.html#hH-3868571d-e754-42a2-840e-6629e817903b). I am trying to generate 100 instances of the actor and add it to the actor system, however, I can only pass in the class type instead of an instance of that class. Does it have to be recursive where a parent has to exist?

```
class Person(Actor):
    def __init__(self, name):
        pass
```

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    from thespian.actors import ActorSystem
    system = ActorSystem()
    for i in range(100):
        system.createActor(Person("*insert unique name*"))
    # Shutdown ActorSystem instance.
    system.shutdown()
```

It doesn't seem like this is allowed given the Thespian documentation, but couldn't find anything online about this use case.

Comment: See this issue on the Thespian tracker: https://github.com/thespianpy/Thespian/issues/18